# Data sharing on the private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, storage

Assuming that there are multiple parties on the private blockchain, few general questions on the private blockchain usage:

1. Can Personally identifiable information (PII) data be stored on blockchain? does it fall under good architecture?
2. Lets say Party A (Entity) created a some data for one of its user U1 on the block chain. Around a week later, Party B just want to check if there exists anything on that blockchain for the same user U1 on the blockchain. Can Party B query on the blockchain on whether any Party created entry for U1?

My understanding is that no one else can read/verify anything on the blockchain for the entry that was created by another Party. Is that correct? If so, if I have the need to do the lookup on the blockchain, how can Party B do the lookup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about Ethereum Blockchain.

1. PII can be stored in the Blockchain as metadata. Or you can use some third party decentralised file storage solutions like [IPFS](http://ipfs.io) till the [Swarm](https://forum.ethereum.org/categories/swarm) is mature enough to be used in Dapps.
2. Yes, they can view data and verify it. It is there in the Blockchain by design.

> **Swarm:** the ethereum decentralized storage protocol

Anyone who participate in a private/public Blockchain can view all the data. In a Blockchain all the data are stored as transactions, you can associate metadata to that transactions to do whatever you want to do with the data.

*Or even we can write some script to read the data from the Blockchain directly.*

**Take a look at**

1. Ethreum RPC
2. Web3js
3. Swarm
4. IPFS